# for matlab 2014b the .eps files are not openning with evince and okular

Tags: matlab, plot, matlab-figure, eps, okular

I am using Matlab2014b in ubuntu14.04, before I was using Matlab2013b in windows7 system. The eps files from Matlab2014b are not openning with evince or okular document viewers and hanging the system. I have some eps files written with Matlab2013b which can be easily opened with these document viewers without hanging the system.

Later I realized that the eps files written with Matlab2013b have header as follow

```
%!PS-Adobe-2.0 EPSF-1.2 %%Creator: MATLAB, The MathWorks, Inc. Version 8.2.0.701 (R2013b). Operating System: Microsoft Windows 7.
```

and with eps files written with Matlab2014b have header as follow

```
%!PS-Adobe-3.0 EPSF-3.0 %%Creator: (MATLAB, The Mathworks, Inc. Version 8.4.0.150421 \(R2014b\). Operating System: Linux) Moreover the later was a very long file.
```

I have also asked with question on Mathworks website.

How can I fix this problem?

Regards, Abdullah

Comment: How do you save your eps files? what code do you use?

Comment: Dear Biguri. I use "print -depsc filename" command to make an .eps file in the working directory of the matlab.

Comment: I recommend you use some other function to save them. Try exprot_fig from Matlab FileExchange.

Comment: Dear Biguri, used the export_fig, it is working very fine. Thank you for your response. I want to know that MATLAB and this function are exporting in the same pdf and eps versions why computer gets stuck with the matlab print command. Regards

Comment: The figure system in Matlab version previous than R2014b is very far from  effective. I had a lot of problems in my career due to wrongly saved figures by Matlab. Nowadays, there are no more problems with the new figure system, it seems that they realised that they were doing that worldly. But as they were problems somebody created export_fig and nowadays its the most downloaded file in the wwbpage. So you are not alone, it is just that Matlab had that wrongly programmed.